# How to decode a barcode image using ZXing library in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application based on the zxing library using intent and I would like the user to be able to decode a barcode image that is stored on the sd card.

Since i am beginner in android,please tell me in detail about

1. How to integrate ZXing with the application
2. How to get a image file from sd card onto the application
3. Finally how to decode the barcode image file and store the decoded result.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

Download the file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-1.6.zip).

This is a complete library. In it you will find an already-built Android Project. Just import it in Eclipse.

You will face packages missing problem. But in the downloaded library there is folder core 
in which you will find all the classes required. if not then proceed.

In the downloaded library you will find a android integration project. This code tells how to embed and use scanning in your application. It will call the already installed zxing app for scanning.

It would be preferable to have the scanning code within your app.
So for that research on the CaptureActivity project and manipulate it as per your requirement.
I had done it. It took time though. Just be good in Java. You will be able to do it also.

Comment: Once you will embed the activity for scanning through camera. you will also then going to know how to pass directly the file from sd card

Comment: thanks a lot for quick reply. I will try and get back to u soon...Thank u.

Comment: Hi i want to decode a barcode image present resources. So where should i write the corresponding code, i mean in android test or android-captureActivity. If possible please provide an example source code of applications related to zxing.